# How to do Xamarin.UITest for Splash Screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have a project in Xamarin.Forms which have splash screen.
I need to do a Xamarin.UItest for splash screen.
How can I achieve it as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but you will probably be unable to do so.
I guess that your splash screen disappears after a few seconds. Although Xamarin.UITest should technically support the splash screen, you cannot rely on Xamarin.UITest to be quick enough to catch your splash screen before it disappears.